# SOQL Polymorphism Results

Tags: soql, polymorphism

What kind of result set is returned from this SOQL and can I write this inside a for loop?

```
[SELECT Name, Description,
    TYPEOF OwnerId
        WHEN Folder THEN Name
    END
    FROM Report]
```

Comment: Anything can go inside a for loop, but if it's in a trigger you're going to hit governor limits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a polymorphic query recently introduced by Force.com platform

Since Report ownerId can belong to Folder,organisation or user in Report Object now using TYPE OF gives flexiblity to query .Now If its folder Type then return name

same say you had one more Organisation in query since ownerId can refrence to organisation too .

eg:

```
[SELECT Name, Description,
TYPEOF Owner
    WHEN Folder THEN Name
    WHEN Organistion THEN ID
    WHEN User THEN ID
END
FROM Report]
```

Now if owner Id is Folder the query will select Name 
If owner ID id user the Id is returned in the query

The end result will be Report object type and yes you can have in for loop.

Check the documentation for more info

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm#relates_and_polymorph_keys

```
List<rReport> lstrep=[SELECT Name, Description,
TYPEOF Owner
    WHEN Folder THEN Name
    WHEN Organistion THEN ID
    WHEN User THEN ID
END
FROM Report]

 for(Report r:lstrep){
  //Say to refer folder name
  String n=r.Owner.Name;
  Id xyz=r.Owner.Id;//If it is fetched from the Folder this will be null

  //do processing
  }
```

Comment: What about how to use the results of the query in apex?

Comment: @DanielBlackhall the results as i said will be of List<Object> type and like normal queries we can use in for loop too

Comment: can you post an example in your answer? and delete the duplicate url while you're at it

Comment: The one thing I really wanted to see, you left out :) how do I refer to the Folder.Name or User.Id in code?

Comment: @DanielBlackhall Thanks for bringing to notice updated the information and answer

Comment: I think I was confused. I was thinking that 'WHEN Folder THEN Name' was going to return Folder.Name instead of just the Name of the report. I see now that this SOQL would return Report objects instead of an aggregate result like I was thinking it might. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I try the suggested query in a SOQL query tool such as the Developer Console or SOQLExplorer and I get this error message.

SOQL TYPEOF expressions are not supported in this organization

Searching for cause leads to:

[Is SOQL Polymorphism enabled by default in API 26?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/2210/is-soql-polymorphism-enabled-by-default-in-api-26)

Which takes you to here: http://blogs.developerforce.com/tech-pubs/2012/09/soql-polymorphism-or-how-i-learned-to-love-the-polymorphic-relationship.html

Which says this is a feature that needs to be enabled by contacting SF.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the SObject interface to dereference.  I have not found a way to do it statically.

```
final List<Report> theReports=[SELECT OwnerId, Name, Description,
    TYPEOF Owner
        WHEN Folder THEN Name
        WHEN Organization THEN Id
        WHEN User THEN Id
    END
    FROM Report
    LIMIT 20];


for(Report current :theReports){
  // Refer to Owner by SObject
  final SObject theOwner = current.Owner;

  // Be careful to check "isSet()"
  // otherwise: System.SObjectException: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: User.Name
  final String theOwnerName = theOwner != null && theOwner.isSet('Name') ? (String) theOwner.get('Name') : null;
  final Id theOwnerId = theOwner != null && theOwner.isSet('Id') ? (Id) theOwner.get('Id') : null;

  // Do something clever to ensure you use the right field  
  final String theOwnerLabel = theOwnerName != null ? theOwnerName : theOwnerId;

  // Prove it worked
  System.debug('Owner: ' + theOwnerLabel + ' ' + current);
}
```