# Is SOQL Polymorphism enabled by default in API 26?

Tags: soql, api-26, polymorphism

Is SOQL Polymorphism enabled by default in API 26? I'm getting the error 'SOQL TYPEOF expressions are not supported in this organization' error when deploying to my test org that's on API 26.

Comment: @metadaddy are there any updates? I wrote a SOQL on v.38 and still get this error, didn't they make it GA?
This still tells me its not: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000175996&language=en_US&type=1
Or can I just ask support to enable it?

Comment: @Basti I left Salesforce nearly a year ago, so I no longer have an 'inside track' on this :-(

Comment: @metadady oh okay thanks though! Meanwhile, I asked support, it's not GA and they could not tell me more except they will let us know when it is...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Per the [release notes](https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesforce_winter13_release_notes.pdf), SOQL Polymorphism is in Developer Preview in API 26 (Winter 13). You'll need to contact salesforce.com to get it enabled. See [this blog entry](http://blogs.developerforce.com/tech-pubs/2012/09/soql-polymorphism-or-how-i-learned-to-love-the-polymorphic-relationship.html) for more on SOQL Polymorphism.

Comment: Seems that support won't enable it - I'm investigating...

Answer (score 1):

`TYPEOF` is going GA in [Summer 19](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer19/release-notes/rn_api_soql.htm#rn_api_soql) in API v46.0