# Help with SOQL Query on Event to get Opportunity Fields

Tags: soql

I'm trying to construct a query on Event to retrieve some custom fields on Opportunity in the same query as the Event fields. The "`WhatID`" is the `Opportunity.Id`. The `WhoID` is unrelated to the Account. The `OwnerID` owns the Opportunity.

I keep getting the error message that Apex doesn't understand the relationship of `Opportunity`, `Opportunity__r`, `Opportunities`, `Opportunities__r`, etc., regardless of what I seem to do; including enclosing that portion in a separate sub select.

Here's what I want to select:

```
Assnmnt = [select Id, OwnerID, Owner.Name, Subject, ActivityDateTime, ActivityDate, DurationInMinutes, StartDateTime, EndDateTime, Description, WhatID, WhoID, Who.Name, What.Opportunity.Account_Address__c, What.Opportunity.Account.Name, What.Opportunity.Account_Phone__c, Opportunty__r.Customer_Contact__c from Event Where Id =: Asn2Create and WhatId =: What.Opportunity.Id];
```

Any help on how to properly construct this to work would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to create the query in eclipse or Force.com Explorer? You will get the relationship names automatically over there.

Comment: Yes I have. I tried Ajax tools, the equiv of Force.com Explorer. It doesn't take me "up" to Opportunity, only to Accounts of which Opportunity is a child. Opportunity is the parent of the Event. Problem is, Apex doesn't know that because What can be a number of things and I have no way of telling it that or don't know how to!

Answer (score 3):

In the query example you provided above, "`What`" is already the Opportunity, you don't need to "drill-in" to a reference off of that field. So, you should be able to access Opportunity fields using `What.[Opportunity-Field-Name]` as long as the fields you are querying are Standard fields.

To query custom fields from a related object on Tasks or Events, you could use [`TYPEOF`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm#soql_polymorph_keys) in a SOQL statement, but you'd [need to contact Salesforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/2210/is-soql-polymorphism-enabled-by-default-in-api-26) to get it enabled first.

I'm not entirely sure if this would work because I don't have TYPEOF enabled, but you could try this:

```
// where getOpportunityId is a method that returns the Opportunity Id
My_Opportunity_ID = getOpportunityId(); 

Assnmnt = [
    SELECT 
        Id, OwnerID, Owner.Name, Subject, ActivityDateTime, ActivityDate, 
        DurationInMinutes, StartDateTime, EndDateTime, Description,  WhatID, WhoID, 
        Who.Name, 
        TYPEOF What 
            WHEN Opportunity THEN Account_Address__c, Account.Name, 
                 Account_Phone__c, Customer_Contact__c 
        END
    FROM Event 
    WHERE Id = :Asn2Create 
    AND WhatId = :My_Opportunity_ID
    AND What.Type = 'Opportunity'
];
```

Comment: I had considered trying something like: `system.debug(whatID + ' = ' + Opportunity.get(WhatId));` or similar, but hadn't figured out what it should look like until your post. What you've suggested is giving me the following error message: No such column 'Account_Address__c' on entity 'Name'. It appears this is close, but I think we now have Opp name and not Opportunity.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense actually. The "`What`" field is a polymorphic key (references multiple types of objects). If I remember correctly, custom fields aren't available from polymorphic key fields.

Comment: Thanks for trying. Good info to know though for future use. :) Will work around it either using another query or doing string ops on other fields in the event; something I was trying to avoid.(sigh)